# MySQL - Delete related rows based on search result from a different column

Tags: mysql, database

Having trouble trying to delete multiple related rows from a **MySQL table** "postmeta"

I've used this function to find rows where **"_edd_log"** / **meta_value** = 0

```
DELETE FROM `postmeta`
WHERE `meta_key` = "_edd_log" AND `meta_value` = 0;
```

This removes the rows correctly but I've realised I want to also delete any rows which are related by **post_id**

| row | post_id | meta_key | meta_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 385 | _edd_log | 0 |
| 02 | 385 | _edd_usr | name1 |
| 03 | 385 | _edd_pan | 72767 |
|  |  |  |  |
| 04 | 386 | _edd_log | 512 |
| 05 | 386 | _edd_usr | name2 |
| 06 | 386 | _edd_pan | 72767 |
|  |  |  |  |
| 07 | 387 | _edd_log | 0 |
| 08 | 387 | _edd_usr | name3 |
| 09 | 387 | _edd_pan | 72767 |

So, in this example table, it would find **row 01** as a match (for edd_log = 0) and see the post_id as **385**.

I need it to then **delete all rows where post_id is 385** (ie 01-03).

Then it would carry on to find **row 07** (edd_log = 0) and delete rows 07-09 (**matching post_id 387**)

and so on...

Any help is gratefully appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM `postmeta`
WHERE post_id IN 
  (SELECT post_id FROM `postmeta`
   WHERE `meta_key` = "_edd_log" AND `meta_value` = 0);
```

Comment: I have a memory issue with this one when I simulate it.  Fatal Error Allowed memory size of 209715200 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 81300672 bytes). Is there a trick to temporarily increase memory in MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

Join the table to a query that returns the `post_id` that satisfies your conditions:

```
DELETE p
FROM postmeta p 
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT post_id 
  FROM postmeta
  WHERE meta_key = '_edd_log' AND meta_value = 0
) t  ON t.post_id = p.post_id;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c021a0b9cd2bb30da7a7a5772050fe16).